# Power Calculations for Diff-in-Diff with Fixed Effects

Tags: experiment-design, statistical-power, difference-in-difference, gpower

I am conducting a field experiment. Where we observe two different optimization methods.

First 7 days pre-treatment period and 28 days treatment period.
To split treatment and control, we will have different geo-blocks each containing 2 regions one for treatment one for control. We us a Diff-in-Diff Analysis with Fixed Effects for Day and Region.
Effect Size is around 7%-10%.

I have tried finding a guide on how to calculate power for such a design to tell me how many geo-blocks I need to have for a power of 0.8 with 0.95 significance. I have looked into clusterPower, however this experiment does not have subjects in the common sense (days would be the subjects). Is there a more tailored way of calculating power for a Diff-in-Diff with fixed effects?

Does anybody have knowledge on how to simulate the power or a good source?